# Is this possible to calculate p value in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below and would like to calculate p value by comparing TRT vs CTR. Is this doable in oracle sql? I used to calculate expected value by different random group in excel, then use chitest function to get p value.

```
RANDOM_GROUP    Count   FLAG
       1          67    CTR
       2          43    CTR
       3          43    CTR
       4          44    CTR
       5          34    CTR
       6          30    CTR
       7          58    CTR
       8          72    CTR
       9          54    CTR
      10          63    CTR
      11         492    CTR
       1          42    TRT
       2          54    TRT
       3          38    TRT
       4          44    TRT
       5          43    TRT
       6          58    TRT
       7          65    TRT
       8          59    TRT
       9          52    TRT
      10          68    TRT
      11          477   TRT
```

Comment: So what would be your expected output? Also, what are the two columns that you want to calculate  p` for?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has [arithmetic function `STATS_CROSSTAB()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions185.htm#SQLRF06317).

I think that you are looking for the `'CHISQ_SIG'` value (as per the documentation, this is the *significance of observed chi-squared*):

It is hard to tell which two columns you want to analyze out of the 4 columns available in your sample data. Here is an example with `TRT` and `CTR`:

```
SELECT STATS_CROSSTAB(TRT, CTR, 'CHISQ_SIG') p_value FROM mytable
```

Comment: thank you! I modified my question, could you take a look?

Comment: @user11245230: it is usually not a good practice to substantially modify the question after answers were posted. Are you able to adapt the query in my answer to your exact use case (I think that you just need to change the column names in the call to `STATS_CROSSTAB()`)?

Comment: Also, my p value is integer, not decimal. How can I change it? Thanks!

Comment: yes, thank you! I'm able to adapt this query but p value returns as 1 and chi_squared as 0. I think i need to change to decimal. right now it's showing integer.

Comment: @user11245230: as per [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions185.htm#SQLRF06317), `STATS_CROSSTAB` returns `NUMBER`  values, not specifically integer values...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`stats_crosstab()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions185.htm#SQLRF06317) function, which is described here in the documentation.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f08a1a4cb8c38e0abd229a86ae184288) is a small db<>fiddle.